# How to disable location services from app for that app only?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app which uses location services. I want to disable the location for that app only by just toggling UISwitch in the app settings. So is it possible that I can enable or disable the access location from the app itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can just bind that switch to a method where you set a boolean in User Defaults (something like USER_LOCATION_ENABLED).

```
-(void)switchAction:(id)sender {

   UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
   if(theSwitch.isOn) {
      [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:YES forKey:@"USER_LOCATION_ENABLED"];
   } else {
      [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:NO forKey:@"USER_LOCATION_ENABLED"];
   }
   [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Then, in your code, only start location services if USER_LOCATION_ENABLED is set to true.

```
-(void)startLocationServices {
   if([[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] objectForKey:@"USER_LOCATION_ENABLED"]) {
      [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 
   {
}
```